# action_send mime type for links

Tags: android, mime-types

When someone longpresses a link and chooses share link and select my app it grabs it and does what it does.. but this also works with other sharable text items. I would like to only accept links. Currently i have the mime type as text/plain. Is there a mime type for links?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, sorry. At least for the standard Android browser, it uses `text/plain`. You are welcome to examine the value that is sent to you, see if it looks like a URL via a regular expression, and pop up an error indicating that you only send links.

In theory, you could even then turn around and execute `startActivity()` for the same `Intent`, to allow the user to choose something else to try sharing with. I have not tried this, though, so there could be some hiccups here that I am not aware of.